# How to install Google Cloud SDK app-engine-python on Debian 12?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I am using the Debian 12 operating system, and I have the latest version of the Google Cloud SDK installed, currently at version 454.0.0. I am attempting to install the Google Cloud App Engine Python component using the following command:

`apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python`

However, this package still depends on python2.7, which is **not installable** on Debian 12. Is there any known workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Cloud App Engine Python component depends on python2.7, which is not available on Debian 12. There is currently no known workaround for this issue.

There is a bug raised for this at [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/265528492), which is still open. You can add your concern over there and further progress can be tracked there.